# Como Relacionar uma Tabela com Outra Tabela onde o campo para relacionar é um XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select

Estou com um banco SQL Server de um sistema que foi descontinuado. Neste banco, existe uma tabela `MOVIMENTACAO` e uma tabela `EQUIPAMENTO`, onde configuraria um relacionamento `N:N`.

O problema é que ao invés de ter uma terceira tabela, há um campo na tabela `MOVIMENTACAO` com os *IDs* dos `EQUIPAMENTOS` em formato *XML*.

EX:

```html
<ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <int>39254</int>
  <int>39255</int>
  <int>79349</int>
  <int>79351</int>
  <int>79354</int>
  <int>79456</int>
  <int>79539</int>
  <int>79547</int>
</ArrayOfInt>
```

Dúvida: Há alguma forma de montar uma *QUERY* onde eu possa fazer esse relacionamento?

Comment: Se entendi correto, que POG fizeram aí hein. Acredito que o melhor seja jogar isso em uma linguagem de programação, criar uma regra para tratar esses IDs jogado nesse xml e fazer uma relação N:N realmente válida.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma seria normalizar estes dados em uma tabala gerada da relação N:N e alterar o código da aplicação para lidar com esta nova estrutura.

Se isso não for possível, podemos fazer o seguinte:

Tabela MOVIMENTACOES

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela EQUIPAMENTOS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora precisamos criar um script que normalize o XML em linhas (equipamentos) junto com suas respectivas movimentações.

```
/*Tabela virtual para armazenar a relação N:N*/
DECLARE @TAB_NORMALIZADA TABLE(
  cod_movimentacao int,
  cod_equipamento int
)

/*Normalização dos dados*/
INSERT INTO @TAB_NORMALIZADA
SELECT 
  cod_movimentacao,
  T2.lin.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM   MOVIMENTACOES
CROSS APPLY xml_equipamentos.nodes('/ArrayOfInt/int') as T2(lin)

/*Select com nome do equipamento e código de movimentação*/
SELECT 
  T.* ,
  E.equipamento
FROM @TAB_NORMALIZADA T INNER JOIN EQUIPAMENTOS E
ON T.cod_equipamento = E.cod_equipamento
```

Se você puder alterar a estrutura do banco, crie uma tabela nova para substituir a minha tabela virtual e uma trigger na tabela de movimentação para popular esta nova tabela.